# Supabase Flutter initialization is failing

Tags: flutter, dart, supabase, supabase-flutter

this is exception, which i got in debug console, while i tried to debug my app. ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
Launching lib\main.dart on ONEPLUS A3010 in debug mode...
/C:/Users/saaho/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/supabase_flutter-1.0.0-dev.1/lib/src/supabase_auth.dart:43:3: Error: Type 'GotrueSubscription' not found.
  GotrueSubscription? _authSubscription;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/saaho/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/supabase_flutter-1.0.0-dev.1/lib/src/supabase_auth.dart:303:5: Error: Type 'AuthOptions' not found.
    AuthOptions? options,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^

/C:/Users/saaho/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/supabase_flutter-1.0.0-dev.1/lib/src/supabase_auth.dart:43:3: Error: 'GotrueSubscription' isn't a type.
  GotrueSubscription? _authSubscription;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/saaho/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/supabase_flutter-1.0.0-dev.1/lib/src/supabase_auth.dart:111:16: Error: 'GotrueError' isn't a type.
          } on GotrueError catch (error) {
               ^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/saaho/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/supabase_flutter-1.0.0-dev.1/lib/src/supabase_auth.dart:91:58: Error: 'onAuthStateChange' isn't a function or method and can't be invoked.
          Supabase.instance.client.auth.onAuthStateChange((event, session) {
                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/saaho/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/supabase_flutter-1.0.0-dev.1/lib/src/supabase_auth.dart:109:68: Error: The getter 'data' isn't defined for the class 'AuthResponse'.
- 'AuthResponse' is from 'package:gotrue/src/types/auth_response.dart' ('/C:/Users/saaho/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/gotrue-1.11.2/lib/src/types/auth_response.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'data'.

              _instance._initialSessionCompleter.complete(response.data);
                                                                   ^^^^
/C:/Users/saaho/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/supabase_flutter-1.0.0-dev.1/lib/src/supabase_auth.dart:282:10: Error: 'GotrueError' isn't a type.
    } on GotrueError catch (error) {
         ^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/saaho/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/supabase_flutter-1.0.0-dev.1/lib/src/supabase_auth.dart:303:5: Error: 'AuthOptions' isn't a type.
    AuthOptions? options,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/saaho/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/supabase_flutter-1.0.0-dev.1/lib/src/supabase_auth.dart:305:23: Error: The method 'signIn' isn't defined for the class 'GoTrueClient'.
- 'GoTrueClient' is from 'package:gotrue/src/gotrue_client.dart' ('/C:/Users/saaho/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/gotrue-1.11.2/lib/src/gotrue_client.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'signIn'.
    final res = await signIn(
                      ^^^^^^

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter dev\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1201

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter dev\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 4m 25s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

environment > flutter: ^3.10.2 | dart: ^3.0.2

this is my main function.------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:supabase_flutter/supabase_flutter.dart';

void main () async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Supabase.initialize(
    url: 'https://dwjxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.supabase.co',
    anonKey: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  );
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  await Hive.openBox("MainBox");
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using an old developer preview version of supabase_flutter. Try using the lastest version by adding the following in your pubspec.yaml file.

```yaml
supabase_flutter: ^1.10.11
```